# Haskell gloss loading .bmp

Tags: haskell, gloss

```
-- | Main function
main :: IO ()
main = do 
          wall <- loadBMP "wall.bmp" -- loads wall image
          play initialState drawState reactEvent reactTime


-- | Function that creates the game
play :: State -> (State -> Picture) -> (Event -> State -> State) -> (Float -> State -> State) -> IO ()
play initialState drawState reactEvent reactTime = play
            (InWindow "Game" (900, 900) (0, 0))      -- Window ize
            (greyN 0.5)                              -- background coloer
            1                                        -- refresh rate
            initialState                             -- initial state
            drawState                                -- draws game state
            reactEvent                               -- teacts to evente
            reactTime                                -- reacts to time

-- | One game represenction
type State = (Map,Picture)

-- | Initial game state
initialState :: State
initialState = ((map 13 0),wall)
```

The function map creates my map.
My game is already running fine, but I need to replace the representations i used (circles from gloss) with some BMP images, but i can't load even one cause when i try to load this wall it appears an error in the last line I shared here:
not in scope 'wall'

Can someone see why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

When you define `main`, the variables you create there aren't accessible outside of the definition of `main`. `initialState` is outside the definition of `main`.

You need to pass `wall` into `initialState` by changing `main` and `initialState` like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
          wall <- loadBMP "wall.bmp" -- loads wall image
          play (initialState wall) drawState reactEvent reactTime
```

```
initialState :: Picture -> State
initialState wall = ((map 13 0),wall)
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this and tell how it goes.